# Express/MongoDB app on Heroku Content Security Policy problem loading images from another domain (and even jQuery from cdn...)

Tags: jquery, express, heroku, content-security-policy

I'm developing a web app page that loads a couple of images from `example.com/repo` and my AWS S3, plus jQuery from `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-etc`.

It was working on localhost, not on Heroku. The only thing I got working is Google fonts. Here's my meta in Pug, (le n'emporte quoi, I know...):

```
meta(http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://www.example.com; script-src 'self' https://code.jquery.com/; style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com; img-src 'self' s3://mybucket/ https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/images/ https://www.example.com/repo/; font-src fonts.gstatic.com")
```

Here is the console output. What am I missing? Thanks in advance:

> Content Security Policy: Couldn’t process unknown directive ‘script-src-attr’
> Loading failed for the  with source “https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js”.

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js (“script-src”).

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://www.example.com/repo/bgr.jpg (“img-src”).

Answer (score 0):

> Content Security Policy: Couldn’t process unknown directive
> ‘script-src-attr’

says that you have a second CSP issued somewhere, since your  showed CSP does not have *script-src-attr* directive.

Check in HTML code the presence second `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy">`, and in developer tool - presence the CSP header.